# Convert LatLng to (x, y) coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, latitude-longitude

I'm working on Google maps which will show multiple vehicles. I've two points(one point which will be the old position and other will be the present position) this positioning system will help write an equation of a line passing through these two points. Which might intersect with other line and inform me about the probability of collision.

But the problem is that I'm fetching the coordinates from the GPS module and it will give the location in Latitude and Longitude format.

I'll need x, y coordinates for this writing the equation of the line passing through them. I've already explored most of the method in different web pages, but the problem is that they will ask for some screen size(or map bounds) which are kind of not compatible with my type of method.

*Questions:* What is the method to convert Latitude and Longitude to (x, y) coordinates, just like if we see from the space and earth was flat and taking Gulf of Guinea (Lat: 0°, Lon: 0°) as the origin.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your task requires high accuracy you have to use Latitude/Longitude and to solve Great Circle intersection task. The Earth is not flat.
2. If you can accept existence of some error in your calculations AND all of your vehicles are located in small limited area (up to 100km, although it depends on error you can accept) you may assume this confined area as flat.

For instance, if one your vehicle is located at N10.0 E10.0, second one is located at N10.1 E10.2, you may choose N10.0 E10.0 as the origin.

As a result, these two vehicles will have the following (X, Y) coords (it assumes that axis X goes along equator):
   1) (0.0km    0.0km)
   2) (21.86km  11.1km)

X of second vehicle is (40000km / 360 degrees) * cos(10.0) * (10.2 - 10.0) = 21.86km

Y of second vehicle is (40000km / 360 degrees) * (10.1 - 10.0) = 11.1km

If you will try to apply flat line-line intersection for vehicles located in 10 000 km from each other - your calcutions most probably will be incorrect.

Comment: Ok. Author tries to find trajectory intersection actually. If he tries to use trivial line equation like a*x + b*y = c for two **distant** vehicles the result can be erroneous. However such equation can be used (with some acceptable error) if distance between vehicles is small.